# Explode operation on arabic text coming from a text file

Tags: php

I have a file that contains arabic and english characters.
I need to read the file and make an explode operation on the text.

Although the text coming from the file shows the chracters correctly, when I apply `explode` it prints different characters like 搀椀愀氀漀ⴀ愀✀ 
What can I do to fix it?

```
$file = fopen("files/MetinCeviriKelimeler.txt","r");
$temp=fgets($file); 
echo $temp;
$explode_str = explode('>',$temp);
echo $explode_str[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `mb_split()` instead (it's technically a regular expression for the first argument, but for your purposes you can use it exactly the same as you would `explode()`).

Normal php string functions tend to mangle UTF text;
there's a whole library of mb_ functions to preserve the encoding.

**-- Edit --**

You can also set:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

somewhere at the top of your file.  For it to take effect, your source code files need to be encoded as UTF8 as well.